# Doctrine ORM serialization after join

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I guys I am working diwth doctrine JOINS and I came across a problem.

I have done a query with joins and it seems ok, the results are good! but the output is terrible

```
public function getMarketcapData($page = -1, $limit = -1){
      $pageAndCount = $page>-1 && $limit>0;
      $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

      $q  = $qb->select('cc, count(cr) as coinRawsCount, cmc as relatedCategory')
              ->from('AppBundle:CoinClean', 'cc')
              ->leftJoin("AppBundle:CoinRaw", "cr",  'WITH', 'cc = cr.coinClean')
              ->leftJoin("AppBundle:CoinMapCategory", "cmc", 'WITH', 'cc.relatedCategory = cmc')
              ->andWhere('cc = cr.coinClean')
              ->andWhere('cc.relatedCategory = cmc')
              ->groupBy('cc.id')
      ;

      if($pageAndCount) $q = $q->setFirstResult($page*$limit)->setMaxResults($limit);

      $q= $q->orderBy('cc.rank', "ASC")->getQuery();

      $result = $q->getResult();
      if($pageAndCount){
          $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
          $q = $qb->select('count(u.id)')->from('AppBundle:CoinClean', 'u')->getQuery();
          return new PageResult($result, (int)$q->getSingleScalarResult(), $page, $limit );
      }else{
          return $result;
      }
  }
```

here you have the output: it is an array made by array + obejcts

```
data:[
   [ // first query result
    {data from cc} // ony one object
   ], 
   {// first query result from join
     "coinRawsCount": 4,
     "relatedCategory": {...}
   },
   [ // second query result
     {data from cc2} // ony one object
   ], 
   {// second query result from join
    "coinRawsCount": 4,
    "relatedCategory": {...}
   }
]
```

my goal is to condense all in

```
"data":[
  {
    "data": {...},
    "coinRawsCount": 4,
    "relatedCategory": {...}
  },
  {
    "data": {...},
    "coinRawsCount": 4,
    "relatedCategory": {...}
  },
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the result and merge on every other row, e.g. like this:

```php
$rows = $q->getResult();
$result = []

foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
    if ($row instanceof App\Entity\CoinClean) {
        // Skip first row and merge data when reading next row
        continue;
    }
    $result[] = array_merge(
        ['data' => $rows[$index - 1]],
        $row
    );
}

return $result;
```

Assuming the first row is always the entity, we will skip this entry using `continue;`. The next row should contain an array with the additional data. We can then take the previous offset (`$index - 1`) to fetch the entry and the current row and merge them together. You might have to do additional checks.

Keep in mind that you will loop over a potentially large array and since you copy the data over to a new array this might use up a considerable amount of memory. So you might have to profile and optimize it, if you notice poor performance.

Other options would be to perform a native SQL query and then just map the output using a [ResultSetMappingBuilder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html) or to use custom hydration, i.e. create a new custom DTO-object for that query, that better fits the resulting data than the original entity structure, using DQL `SELECT NEW App\Dto\MyModel FROM ...your query...'`.

Comment: Then ResultSetMapping or custom hydration would be good options. I like the latter, because you can create a small Read Only-Object just for the pagination that is optimized for the specific use case. The major downside is, that you can not use it to modify data and may lead to problems, when the underlying models/schema change, which might not be apparent, so you should write proper functional tests for the query.